# Counting characters, digits, spaces and newlines in the loaded file

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote an application that loads a file after pressing button and counts characters, digits, spaces and newlines in the loaded file. This application is written in Python language using tkinter library and OOP programming paradigm.

**4programmers.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.filePath = StringVar()
        self.filePath.set("File not loaded")
        self.charLength = StringVar()
        self.charLength.set(0)
        self.digitsLength = StringVar()
        self.digitsLength.set(0)
        self.spacesLength = StringVar()
        self.spacesLength.set(0)
        self.entersLength = StringVar()
        self.entersLength.set(0)

        root.title("A program that counts characters, digits, spaces and newlines in the given file.")

        topFrame1 = Frame(root)
        topFrame1.pack( side = TOP )
        Label(topFrame1, text="Chars count: ").pack( side = LEFT )
        lblCharLength = Label(topFrame1, textvariable=self.charLength)
        lblCharLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

        topFrame2 = Frame(root)
        topFrame2.pack( side = TOP )
        Label(topFrame2, text="Digits count: ").pack( side = LEFT )
        lblDigitsLength = Label(topFrame2, textvariable=self.digitsLength)
        lblDigitsLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

        topFrame3 = Frame(root)
        topFrame3.pack( side = TOP )
        Label(topFrame3, text="Spaces count: ").pack( side = LEFT )
        lblSpacesLength = Label(topFrame3, textvariable=self.spacesLength)
        lblSpacesLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

        topFrame4 = Frame(root)
        topFrame4.pack( side = TOP )
        Label(topFrame4, text="Newlines count: ").pack( side = LEFT )
        lblEntersLength = Label(topFrame4, textvariable=self.entersLength)
        lblEntersLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

        bottomFrame = Frame(root)
        bottomFrame.pack( side = BOTTOM )

        lblFileName = Label(bottomFrame, textvariable=self.filePath)
        lblFileName.pack( side = LEFT )

        btnReadFile = Button(
                bottomFrame,
                text="Load a file",
                fg="black",
                command=self.importFile)
        btnReadFile.pack( side = RIGHT )

    def importFile(self):
        self.filePath.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())

        s = open(self.filePath.get()).read()
        self.charLength.set(len(s))
        self.digitsLength.set(sum(c.isdigit() for c in s))
        self.spacesLength.set(sum(c.isspace() for c in s))
        self.entersLength.set(sum(c == "\n" for c in s))
        self.root.update()

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't use wildcard imports

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that wildcard imports should be avoided. Instead, I recommend you import tkinter like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

This means that everywhere you use a tkinter class or constant you need to prefix it with `tk.`. This will make your program a bit easier to read and understand, especially if you eventually choose to import widgets from ttk which provides many classes with the same name as tkinter classes.

### Group layout commands together

You have calls to `pack` scattered throughout your code, making it difficult to visualize how things are laid out. I strongly recommend grouping your layout code based on parent (ie: call pack on all children that share the same parent)

For example:

```
topFrame1 = Frame(root)
lbl = Label(topFrame1, text="Chars count: ")
lblCharLength = Label(topFrame1, textvariable=self.charLength)

# pack all children of topFrame1 together
lbl.pack( side = LEFT )
lblCharLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

lbl = Label(topFrame2, text="Digits count: ")
lblDigitsLength = Label(topFrame2, textvariable=self.digitsLength)

# pack all children of topFrame2 together
lbl.pack( side = LEFT )
lblDigitsLength.pack( side = RIGHT )

...

# pack all of the children of root together
topFrame1.pack( side = TOP )
topFrame2.pack( side = TOP )
topFrame3.pack( side = TOP )
topFrame4.pack( side = TOP )
bottomFrame.pack( side = BOTTOM )
```

### You don't need StringVar

You don't need to use `StringVar` in your code. The way you are using it means you have more objects, but these objects don't give you any added benefits. Thus, it makes your code more complex than it needs to be.

If you need to change a label at runtime, you can keep a reference and then use the `configure` method to directly change the label.

```
self.lblCharLength = Label(topFrame1, textvariable=self.charLength)
...
self.lblCharLength.configure(text=len(s))
```

If you choose to use them, I recommend setting the value at the time  you create them, which will cut down on the total lines of code:

```
self.filePath = StringVar("File not loaded")
self.charLength = StringVar(value=0)
self.digitsLength = StringVar(value=0)
self.spacesLength = StringVar(value=0)
self.entersLength = StringVar(value=0)
```

### Use `with` to open and read a file

`with` makes it easy to write code that is wrapped by other code. In this case you want to do an open, read some code, and then do a close.

Note: you should also verify that the user picked a path. As written, if the user presses cancel, `self.filePath` will be empty and your code will throw an error.

Also, when you try to cram two or more function calls into a single statement it can make the code harder to debug. By using intermediate variables it makes it easier to pause your program and examine the state.

For example:

```
if filepath:
    self.filePath.set(filepath)   # if using StringVar
    # self.filePath.configure(text=filepath)   # if not using StringVar

    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        s = f.read()
    ...
```

### Avoid calling `update`

At the end of your function `importFile` you call `self.root.update`. That is completely superfluous. The screen will update as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer I'm going to review a single part, and that is the repeated code for generating the various GUI elements related to the counters, and the repeated counter code. Please do read the other answers, and implement the good suggestions from these such as using `with` for the file reading, and so on.

Now let us stretch your imagination a bit, and aim to make it more general. This is based upon the fact that whenever I see variables named with numbers, it triggers some automation mechanism in me.

Any numbered variables could be replaced with an array or list of some sort. In your case you want to test various character characteristics of all text in a file. What if you could add those test methods into a dictionary, and do stuff related to this dictionary?

Luckily, you can actually do that in Python, and you can use your own functions as well:

```
def allChars(c):
    return True

def isnewline(c):
    return c == "\n"

COUNTERS = {
  'Digits'   : str.isdigit,
  'Spaces'   : str.isspace,
  'Newlines' : isnewline,
  'Chars'    : allChars
}
```

Let us then move on to how we can generalize the different part of your original code. Let us start within the `GUI` class:

- For each counter you need to add `StringVar()`s, and set this to 0
- Add a `Frame(root)`
- Add a `Label` with a text
- Add another label for the counter
- Link it all together

Let's create a class to store and do all of this:

```
class NewElement:
  def __init__(self, name, root):
    # Create counter
    self.counter = StringVar()
    self.counter.set(0)

    # Create the GUI part
    self.frame = Frame(root)
    self.frame.pack(side = TOP)
    Label(self.frame, text = "{} count:".format(name)).pack(side = LEFT)
    self.counterLabel = Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.counter)
    self.counterLabel.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

And then the creation within `GUI.__init_` could be simplified into:

```
...
root.title ("A program that counts various thingies")

self.counters = {}

for counter in COUNTERS:
   self.counters[counter] = NewElement(counter, root)

bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)
...
```

Similar in the `importFile` we utilize this array of test functions, like in the following:

```
def importFile(self):
    self.filePath.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())

    s = open(self.filePath.get()).read()

    for c in s:
       for counterType in COUNTERS:
         if COUNTERS[counterType](c):
           self.counters[counterType].counter += 1

    self.root.update()
```

There you have an automated creation of the GUI with predefined counters, and if you would like to add another counter, you simply add another element to the `COUNTERS` dictionary, and rerun your program.

Another benefit of this kind of automated generation, is that if you want to change the element buildup, you change it once within the `NewElement.__init__()` method, and all the corresponding GUI elements are changed. No more copy-pasted code which is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you separate the logic from the presentation.

The counting of different types of characters might be implemented in a class. `__init__` would get the input string as an argument, then count the character types and assign the counts as attributes. This class should be defined in a separate file, say `chartypecounter.py`.

```
class CharTypeCounter:

    def __init__(self, string):

        self.chars = len(string)

        self.digits = 0
        self.spaces = 0
        self.newlines = 0

        for c in string:
            if c.isdigit():
                self.digits += 1

            elif c.isspace():
                self.spaces += 1
                if c == '\n':
                    self.newlines += 1
```

Notice that the way you count characters, you iterate over the input three times. This approach iterates over the string just once, but it's more verbose and its logic is more complicated. It would get messy if the number of character types increased.

Your `GUI.importFile` method would then look like this:

```
    def importFile(self):
        self.filePath.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())

        with open(self.filePath.get()) as f:
            string = f.read()

        counter = CharTypeCounter(string)

        self.charLength.set(counter.char)
        self.digitsLength.set(counter.digit)
        self.spacesLength.set(counter.whitespace)
        self.entersLength.set(counter.newline)

        self.root.update()
```

By implementing the logic outside of the `GUI` class, you can use it elsewhere.

For example you can use `CharTypeCounter` on a string, from the interactive shell, without the need to put that string into a file and start a GUI application to read that file.

```
>>> import chartypecounter as cc
>>>
>>> counter = cc.CharTypeCounter('''
...    some example string
...    123 456 789
... ''')
>>>
>>> counter.__dict__
{'char': 39, 'digit': 9, 'newline': 3, 'whitespace': 13}
```